# Check if a <PackageReference/> tag is added to .csproj file

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I have a .csproj file as follows:

[image: enter code here]

If a `<PackageReference/>` tag is added to this csproj file, the build should fail. How do I do that? Is there any setting or a test I can add?

For example,

[image]

Comment: it's a pretty weird thing to ask. Do you want the build to fail if this NuGet package is installed?

Comment: Correct,  check if PackageReference is added or not - a nuget package is installed or not

Comment: You could read the csproj file in a test and just `string.Contains("PackageReference")`

Comment: As @Adrian wrote, this is a job for a pre-build event, not for a test.

Answer (score 1):

On my phone at the moment, however you can do the following or rather follow this (unable to test for you):

In Pre-Build Events (Right click on your project, go to Properties) of the project, add the following command:

```
CD $(SolutionDir)
CALL CheckProj.ps1
```

Then on the root of your solution, create a bat file called "CheckProj.ps1"

The contents of your script should be along the lines of:

```
$xml = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument;
$xml.LoadXml( (get-content 'MyProject.csproj') );
$node = $xml.SelectNodes('//Project/ItemGroup/PackageReference');
exit $node.Count;
```

Then on the rebuild of the project, if exit isn't equal to 0, it'll fail the build as 0 is expected to simulate success in a build event, anything higher will end up being marked as an error and should fail the whole build process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you'd want to do this, but you could do this in a test fairly easily.

Using XUnit:

```cs
[Fact]
public void NoPackageReferences()
{
    string myCsproj = File.ReadAllText("path/to/my.csproj");
    Assert.DoesNotContain("PackageReference", myCsproj);
}
```

Now, if you wanted to be more thorough, you could parse the XML... But that's probably overkill for this.

Comment: How do I specify path/to/my.csproj? Let’s say I have a project ‘XYZ’ and a test project ‘XYZ.Tests’. How so I specify path to ‘XYZ.csproj’ in ‘XYZ.Tests’ -> Test,cs?

Comment: It'll be relative to the output path of your text project. So something like `../../../../XZY/XYZ.csproj`